# Root problem in Solaris 8

Tags: solaris, root

I am having some troubles on my Solaris 8 computer.
I don't know how this happened, but the path of the user `root` has changed in `/etc/passwd`, therefore I can't become the root user anymore.

Under normal circumstances, the path is like this:

```
root:x:0:1:Super-User:/:/sbin/sh
```

But now it's like this:

```
root:x:0:1:Super-User:/root:/bin/csh
```

The directory `/root` doesn't exist.

I can not edit `/etc/passwd` because I don't have the necessary privileges to do it.

Comment: Can you use `su`, or `sudo` to become root from another user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is on SPARC, boot in single user mode from the OK prompt:

<kbd>Stop</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, then `boot -s`

You should then be able to fix the `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: Thnks for your answer, i'll try it and let you know. And yes it's a SPARC

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `root` password, you should also be able to fix the problem using a simple `su` command (I don't have access to a Solaris 8 system to test):

- Issue the `su` command - without **any** arguments
- Enter the `root` password to become `root` without going through the full login shell process
- Fix the problem.  Either create a `root:root`-owned `/root` directory with `0700` permissions, or restore the `/etc/passwd` entry.  You may need to explicitly set ownership and/or file permissions with `chown` and/or `chmod`.
- Either way, fix the `root` shell and restore it to `/sbin/sh`.  `/bin/csh` is not statically linked and can depend on filesystems not mounted immediately at boot, another way of making the `root` account inaccessible.  **Do not change the `root` shell from `/sbin/sh` on Solaris 8.**  Doing so indicates a lack of understanding of Solaris 8 along with a closed-minded and dangerous fixation on the part of an admin to only using and understanding a limited toolset.

Follow on steps:

- Find a PDF copy of the [Solaris 8 man pages section 1M: System Administration Commands](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0625/index.html)
- Print out the entire book
- Bring printed out pages to a bookbinder
- Bind man pages into big book
- Identify SA who broke the `root` account on this system
- Pound said SA over the head with big `man pages` book for being stupid enough to change the `root` account on a system without understanding the consequences.